# Use ng-Model dynamically based on preset variable

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

So I have the following error:

Given I have the following model:

```
Item {
  key: string,
  name: string,
  data: {
    sectionA: string,
    sectionB: string,
    ...
    sectionZ: string
  }
}
```

I want to dynamically bind the input texts based on an array [A-Z] with a loop

rooms = ["A", "B", ... , "Z"]

```
<div
        class="item"
        ng-repeat="room in rooms"
      >

    <input type="text"
           name="{{ item.key }}"
           class="form-control"
           ng-model="item.data.section"+ room >
</div>
```

It seems that when I loop, I get an error from coffeescript about the model not being valid, so my question is how can I set the right value for the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `item.data.section`, then this will turn to `undefined`, since there isn't a key named `section` in your object and then the `ng-model` would be `undefined + room`, resulting in `undefined`.

You could use `ng-model="item.data['section' + room]"` to refer to your keys. You have a working example below. I added an update function to see that the `ng-model` binding really works.

```js
var module = angular.module("myModule", []);
module.controller("myController", function($scope) {
  $scope.item = {
    key: "itemKey",
    name: "itemName",
    data: {
      sectionA: "section A String ",
      sectionB: "section B String ",
      sectionZ: "section Z String "
    }
  };

  $scope.rooms = ['A', 'B', 'Z'];

  let i = 0;
  $scope.updateValues = function() {
    setInterval(function() {
      Object.keys($scope.item.data).forEach(key => {
        let v = $scope.item.data[key];
        v = v.substr(0, v.length - 1) + i;

        $scope.item.data[key] = v;
        i = (++i) % 10;
      });

      setTimeout(function() {
        $scope.$apply()
      }, 0);
    }, 1000);
  }

  $scope.updateValues();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myModule">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <div class="item" ng-repeat="room in rooms">
      {{ room }}
      <input type="text" name="{{ item.key }}" class="form-control" ng-model="item.data['section' + room]">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Cheers!